# angularjs remove active class on focus and add to next item

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have list of button and input field created with ng-repeat where all buttons and inputs are disabled except the first one. First input and button also contain active class. Active class shows items in red  color. When I focus on the first input item removed the active class.

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UrWOuYlRpGxXEscIT2wL?p=preview)**

Here is what I have:

```
<div class="col-md-2-4 voffset3" ng-repeat="item in csTagGrp">
        <div class="cs-tag-grp-title">
           <input ng-focus="focused=true" disabled type="text" ng-disabled="!$first" ng-class='{active:$first && focused!=true}' class="form-control input-sm"placeholder="Start New Tag Group">
        </div>
        <ul class="list-unstyled cs-tag-item-grp">
           <li class="clearfix" ng-repeat="value in item.csTags">
              <div class="pull-left">
                 <button type="button" ng-disabled="!$parent.$first || !$first" ng-class='{active:$parent.$first && $first}' class="btn btn-default btn-xs">{{value.keys}}</button>
                 <span>=</span>
              </div>
              <div class="pull-left cs-tag-item-list">
                 <input  ng-focus="focused=true"  ng-disabled="!$parent.$first || !$first" ng-class='{active:$parent.$first && $first && focused!=true}' type="text" class="form-control input-sm">
              </div>
           </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

What I am trying to do is. If I focus on the first input 2nd input& button should be enable with the active class. and again if I focus on the 2nd input 3rd input & button will be enable with active class, and goes on ...

As I am very new with angular I am struggling to achieve this. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: demo has different code than in question

Comment: I hope now it's matched !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do this you should write conditions based on your model not based on $first or $last.

Here is the updated **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SPbSthtWAlYgv4WDmcmd)**. Hope this works for you.

```
<div class="col-md-2-4 voffset3" ng-repeat="item in csTagGrp">
  <div class="cs-tag-grp-title">
     <input ng-focus="focusGroup($index)" type="text" ng-disabled="!item.active" ng-class='{active: item.active}' class="form-control input-sm"placeholder="Start New Tag Group">
  </div>
  <ul class="list-unstyled cs-tag-item-grp">
     <li class="clearfix" ng-repeat="value in item.csTags">
        <div class="pull-left">
           <button type="button" ng-disabled="!value.active" ng-class='{active: value.active}' class="btn btn-default btn-xs">{{value.keys}}</button>
           <span>=</span>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-left cs-tag-item-list">
           <input ng-focus="focusItem($index, item.csTags)"  ng-disabled="!value.active" ng-class='{active: value.active}' type="text" class="form-control input-sm">
        </div>
       </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is working good. Only one thing I should mention that when I click on the number 5 , number 6 should active but it's not. It's coming when I press the the Start new tag group.

Comment: Also previous item also remaining red. When focus, active will remove completely just  will only add to the next one

Comment: I thought number 5 and number 6 belongs to two different groups, hence the functionality is limited to its own group. If its not, then we can modify it as per our requirement.

Comment: Tell me how the 'Start new Tag Group' should work. I will help you how to do the remaining part.

Comment: It's like when I focus 1st "Start new group" it will make active to next "Start new group " input field.

Other inputs with number & letter will go one after one. no relation with "start new group"

Thanks for your interest :)

Comment: check the latest plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/3B9nbo?p=preview. Hope this is what you are expecting..

Comment: This is MORE then perfect :) I am going to check how you did that. And Thanks a Ton